# Access Fitnesse Results shown in jenkins in java

Tags: java, api, jenkins, fitnesse

I have scheduled a fitnesse job in Jenkins. Now when the job is complete we can see the result of the job in Fitnesse Results link. I want to access these results through java. Is there any API or something that can help me to access these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can call direct fitnesse test If you want to run the test append your test page by ?test&format=xml and  ?suite&format=xml

```
for ex:- http://localhost:8086/QaTestPage?test&format=xml 
it will return the results something like below

<testResults>
<FitNesseVersion>v20140418</FitNesseVersion>
<rootPath>QaTestPage</rootPath>
<result>
<counts>
<right>0</right>
<wrong>1</wrong>
<ignores>0</ignores>
<exceptions>2</exceptions>
</counts>
<runTimeInMillis>50220</runTimeInMillis>
<content>
{{{ this will have content in HTML format
}}}
</content>
<relativePageName>QaTestPage</relativePageName>
</result>
<finalCounts>
<right>0</right>
<wrong>1</wrong>
<ignores>0</ignores>
<exceptions>0</exceptions>
</finalCounts>
<totalRunTimeInMillis>52985</totalRunTimeInMillis>
</testResults>
```

When we call fitNesse server will return the results as shown above you can parse this XML in your java file

Comment: Already done.. Also we can get the content as a JSON file.. both using Jenkins REST APIs.. Anyways thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1):

You can use rest api of jenkis. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API. Also, every data from job is stored in jenkis workplace home.